# How to add a function to judge that the mouse does not over the icon bar that it disappears automatically

Tags: javascript, popup, tampermonkey

How to add a function to judge that the mouse does not over the icon bar that it disappears automatically

In Tampermonkey, I use a JavaScript that I found in Greasyfork, it will popup when I select words on the website.

I want to achieve this when I move the mouse over the icon bar, it will not disappear, if I do not do that or move out the mouse, the icon bar will disappear automatically.

I used the mouseIn, mouseOver function, they did not work, please help me.

It is the total code in Greasyfork:

[The browser search tool](https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/397040-%E6%B5%8F%E8%A7%88%E5%99%A8%E6%90%9C%E7%B4%A2%E6%89%A9%E5%B1%95%E5%B7%A5%E5%85%B7/code)

The function to judge that the mouse does not over the icon bar:

```
    mouseIn: 0;

    var TimeOutHide = function () {
        if (mouseIn === 0) {
            return icon.style.display = 'none';
        }
    };
```

The icon bar code(part of that):

```
 var iconArray = [
        {
            name: 'Open link',
            image: 'https://i.ibb.co/PQ5xM2R/2-1.png',
            host: [''],
            popup: function (text) {
                if(text.indexOf("http://")==0||text.indexOf("https://")==0)
                window.open(text, "_blank");
                else window.open("http://"+text, "_blank");
            }

        },
]
```

The icon bar automatically disappear When I select words:

```
timer = window.setTimeout(TimeOutHide, 6000);
```

Comment: I find a way that uses js to achieve the event of mouseenter, but it notices this 'Cannot read property 'relatedTarget' of undefined', it does not work yet.


`var hide_controls=function(e){
                        // console.log(this); if(e.relatedTarget!==e.currentTarget&&e.currentTarget.getElementsByClassName(e.relatedTarget.className).length===0){
          icon.style.display = 'none';
         }
    }`


`timer = window.setTimeout(hide_controls, 6000);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is done.

Add two functions:

```
icon.onmouseleave = function(){
}
```

```
icon.onmouseenter = function(){
}
```

Use 'if' to judge the timer, then clear the timer

```
clearTimeout(timer);
```